# Probability of a missile hitting a big ship and a smaller ship - hitting a target problem

Tags: probability

A missile has 5% chance to hit a battleship. The battleship has a surface area of 9500 m^2. If the missile is fired at a smaller Torpedo boat instead, what are the chances that a missile will hit it if the Torpedo boat that has a surface area of 177 m^2?

I am not sure if this is the correct way to calculate that, but:

9500/177 = 53.67

The Torpedo boat is 53.67 times smaller than a battleship.
So a chance to hit the Torpedo boat is:

(0.05/53.67) x 100= 0.0009316 x 100 = 0.093%

But this is probabaly wrong, it likely requires a more complex equation, but I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Nothing in the question allows to assume the probability is proportional to the area of the target. It's true for instance if the missile is fired randomly to some region following a uniform density, but it's a bold assumption. However, you have no way to do it better, so my guess would be that you are supposed to do exactly this.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut that further assumes they are convex, doesn't it?

Comment: @ZoeAllen No. If the missile is fired randomly within some zone $A$, then the probability to hit a target $T$ within $A$ is axactly the area of $T$ divided by the area of $A$. $T$ must be measurable, but is not necessarily convex.

Comment: No, the missile is not fired randomly , and is targeted directly at a battleship, but due to dispersion or just inaccuracy of the targeting system has only 5% chance to hit it.  But anyway, is my calculation then correct? A target that is X amount smaller would be X amount of time harder to hit, and thus the accuracy against the bigger target can be just divided with X like that? Is it correct in that context, assuming no other parameters exist?